# AWS Cognito - How to set first user as admin, every next as user.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Like title, how can I set first registred user as admin and every next as normal user?

Comment: Why not have an admin group and a user group?

Comment: I just want to make it by default

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to simply identify if a certain user is the first to register?  If so, you can use the Post Confirmation lambda trigger. Use a DynamoDB table to maintain a flag (this could be a count)and check this flag to identify if that is the first user to successfully confirm. Change the value of the flag to record that the first user has registered.